# How to say in a formal way that a car outside of the building is ready?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrases, formality

At work today I wanted to tell our guests that a car was waiting for them. Is there a formal way to say that? Are "The car is waiting for you" and "The car is ready" correct?

Comment: By "at work" and "our guests", I assume you work at a hotel, or some other business that offers chaufer services to their guests? Just wanting to be clear on your work place, since it might affect how best to tell your guests that their ride is waiting for them.

Comment: I am electrician engineers and they came to the company to make a contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A formal way to say this would be "The car is now ready at your convenience."

If the car comes with a driver, you might say "Your driver is ready at your convenience." It is implied that the car is also ready (or the driver wouldn't be).

"At your convenience" means "at a time suitable for you." It is a very respectful way to let your guests know that they are not being rushed and that they are being cared for and/or provided a service.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid the suggestion that the car is 'waiting' (which could be seen as impatience) or 'ready' (less intense, but same possible misread connotation), you could simply say the car 'has arrived', and if you want to be formal AND helpful, tell them where it has arrived (at the front of the hotel, in the back of the hotel, at the east/west wing, which you can get to by...).

By saying it has 'arrived', you leave no weight upon your guest's shoulders (a waiting car could lead to the expectation that they should hurry), and more importantly, by telling them where the car is in relation to their own location, you are being very helpful, which the guests are likely to appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

"Your car/taxi is outside" is better.  Then it doesn't feel like you are rushing them.